# Substring first character from right

Tags: r, substr

I want to be able to substring the first character from the right hand side of each element of a vector

```
ABC20
BCD3
B1
AB2222
BX4444
```

so for the group above I would want, C, D, B, B, X .... is there an easy way to this? I know there is a substr and a numindex/charindex. So I think I can use these but not sure exactly in R.

Comment: related: [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use library `stringi`,

```
stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(x, '[A-Z]')
#[1] "C" "D" "B" "B" "X"
```

**DATA**

```
x <- c('ABC20', 'BCD3', 'B1', 'AB2222', 'BX4444')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to capture the last upper case letter (`([A-Z])`) followed by zero or more digits (`\\d*`) until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*([A-Z])\\d*$", "\\1", x)
#[1] "C" "D" "B" "B" "X"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("ABC20", "BCD3", "B1", "AB2222", "BX4444")
```

Comment: When I added my answer with `stringi`, it was NOT in your answer.

Comment: @Sotos I was adding the same answer and I didn't find a new answer

Comment: Ok. I m just saying. I posted it and yours only had the `sub` solution.

Comment: @Sotos I was updating at that time.  Once I posted, I find yours too

Comment: @Sotos I removed the answer.  What I meant is that I came up with the answer independently.  By checking the timings, you posted it first.  It is a fair argument.  Having said that, I noticed many times others posting the same answer as mine (that too after 5 or 10 mins)  and if I  comment, then the obvious reaction would be `when i started typing there was no answer`.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your data:

```
  list<-c("ABC20","BCD3","B1","AB2222","BX4444")
```

Identify position

```
  number_pos<-gregexpr(pattern ="[0-9]",list)
  number_first<-unlist(lapply(number_pos, `[[`, 1))
```

Extraction

```
  substr(list,number_first-1,number_first-1)
[1] "C" "D" "B" "B" "X"
```